# Select selected not working in_array php

Tags: php, multi-select

Is there any way to set the selected item in a drop down box in_array.
but Selected="selected" not working for me.only few Selected value is showing drop down and it's not selected

I tried the following code

```
<label for="assignedto">Assigned to</label>
@foreach($menu as $menus)
   <?php
     $assignedid=$menus->assigned_to;
     $assid[]=explode(',',$assignedid);

   ?>
@endforeach
<?php $maxcount= count($assid); echo '<pre>';print_r($assid); ?>
      <select id="framework1" name="Roles[]" multiple class="form-control" >
        <?php $a= 0;?>          
          @foreach($roles as $id=>$name)
       <?php $newcount=count($assid[$a]);?>
       <option value="{{$id}}"@if(in_array($id, $assid[$a]))selected="selected"@endif>{{$name}}</option>
<?php  
$a++; 
if($a==$maxcount) break; 
?>
@endforeach
```

Here:

```
$assid=Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

And roles array is:

```
$roles=Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [1] => admin
            [12] => asdasd
            [13] => asdfgf
            [4] => manager
            [7] => NewRole
            [8] => NewRole12
            [9] => NewRole13
            [10] => NewRole14
            [11] => NewRole15
            [5] => supervisor
            [6] => Tester
            [2] => user
            [3] => User2
        )

)
```

For first Iteration I want to select ids 4,5,6 means manager,supervisor,Tester should be selected and similarly second iteration 4,5,6 selected etc
But selected for multiple select is not working for me.please help me.any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I hope you would need to re-write the line something link below:

```
<select id="framework1" name="Roles[]" multiple class="form-control" >              
   @foreach($roles as $id=>$name)   
        <option value="{{$id}}" 
         @if(in_array($id, $assid[$a])) 
            selected="selected"
         @endif
         >{{$name}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but its not working same as previous

Comment: Updated the comment, please try again with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use ternary operator in place of "if" -

```
<option value="{{$id}}" <?php echo ((in_array($id, $assid[$a])) ? 'selected="selected"':'')?> >{{$name}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code as below:-

```
<label for="assignedto">Assigned to</label>
<?php $assid = []; // declare array ?>
@foreach($menu as $menus)
<?php
    if(!empty($menus->assigned_to)){ // check if assigned_to key exist in array
        $assignedid=$menus->assigned_to;        
        $assid[]=explode(',',$assignedid);  
    }
?>
@endforeach          

<?php   
  if(!empty($assid)){  
        $assid = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $assid); // It will shift all array elements up one level
  }
  $assid = empty($assid) ? [] : array_combine($assid, $assid); // rewrite this line

?>    

<select id="framework1" name="Roles[]" multiple class="form-control" >              
   @foreach($roles as $id=>$name)   
        <option value="{{$id}}"@if(in_array($id, $assid))selected="selected"@endif>{{$name}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but always 5 values is  get selected.for first iteration i want to select  [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )
6,2,3 only

Comment: Please check updated answer and let me know if problem still exist.

Comment: rewrite this line:- `$assid = empty($assid) ? [] : array_combine($assid, $assid);`

Comment: -answer is same as previous means now 5 item always get selected.i have 4 iteration so first iteration only ids  4,5,6 should selected .but now 4 iteration get same result means 5 items get selected..